# php file transfer from one server to another

Tags: php

I need to transfer a file from  server1 to server2 using html-php. Right now from server1 the download file works fine with following php code, but instead of downloading to client machine, I need this file file to upload to another server, how can I  do this.

Note that the file is not in web directory, I have to read the file from no web directory and transfer to  server2.

```
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filepath).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
        flush(); // Flush system output buffer
        readfile("/home/user/file.ini");
```

Comment: You would need the FTP details of the second server in order to upload to it.

Comment: Is it necessary to have FTP on second server2, actually the server1 and server2 are running apache server.

Comment: FTP stands for File Transfer Protocol, you would need to set an FTP account up on the second server in order to have any form of access to it, do you know if you have this setup?

Comment: You could have a look at [`rsync`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync). this command can be executed from php if needed

Comment: You need to set up some way for the two servers to communicate. It could, for example, be an FTP-server as suggested, an API on server2 that server1 calls and uploads the file to or similar

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson  I am looking solution like method1 on below answer, but it doesn't work. Getting internal server error on executing php.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1: Serve File to Download**

Server 1

```
            $file_name = 'usb.zip';
            $file = '/usr/download/' . $file_name;
            if (file_exists($file))
            {
                if(false !== ($handler = fopen($file, 'r')))
                {
                    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
                    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                    header('Expires: 0');
                    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
                    header('Pragma: public');
                    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
                    //Send Chunks
                    while(false !== ($chunk = fread($handler,4096)))
                    {
                        echo $chunk;
                    }
                }
                exit;
            }
```

Server 2

```
file_put_contents("usb.zip", fopen("http://xxx/file.php", 'r'));
```

**Method 2: Upload via SFTP**

```
$resFile = fopen("ssh2.sftp://{$resSFTP}/".$csv_filename, 'w');
$srcFile = fopen("/home/myusername/".$csv_filename, 'r');
$writtenBytes = stream_copy_to_stream($srcFile, $resFile);
fclose($resFile);
fclose($srcFile);
```

Comment: If I misunderstood, I'm sorry. 
I don't know how to trigger in this case. Triggered by time? When the client calls up?
Well, there are all sorts of ways. What kind of behavior is desired?

Comment: `filename='.basename($file)` Don't do this as it will fail if filename has a comma or any other special characters. Instead do `filename="your_file_name"` by enclosing them in double quotes.

Comment: no, it also works with commas or other special characters.

Comment: I tried the code but getting error `Internal Server Error`, when I comment the code  `if(false !== ($handler = fopen($file, 'r')))`--- the php works.

Comment: Funny, on my machine it works like this. Maybe our PHP versions differ. But if the rest works, I'm glad if I could help

Comment: @CodeDezk if u use $handler = fopen('test.file', 'r') without the if check?

Comment: @MThiele We just faced that issue today on one of our client projects made by some other dev. Hence, I mentioned.

Comment: @vivek_23 thanks for your advice.
In this case the filename is already parsed into a variable and basename is used to include the actual filename in the string. Including special characters or similar. What I can't check is whether windows behaves differently than linux. At least on my linux server I could not reproduce such an error.

Comment: @MThiele Yes, we had this issue on a  windows machine.